# Sending JSON obj with Japanese characters from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, utf-8

I have a Python3 function that when called will return a json object which looks like this:

```html
finished python tags look like this:
{'tags': {'releaseArtist': ['Shuichi Murakami', 'Nobu Caine', 'Electro Keyboard Orchestra', 'Mash', 'Loser', 'Ponta Box', 'Mobo Band', 'JOQR DJ Girls', 'Miro Takebi Trio', 'Nobu-Zans', '7 Seven', 'Ponta Unit'], 'releaseInfo': ['Welcome To My Life', '1998', 'Japan', 'JVC', 'Jazz'], 'tracklist': ['Jaco Pastorius Medley = ジャコ・パトリアス・メドレー', 'I Want You Back = アイ・ウォント・ユー・バック', 'Travelling = トラベリング', 'Ive Got You Under My Skin = アイヴ・ガット・ユー・アンダー・マイ・スキン', '青い山脈', 'Oh! Darling = オー！
ダーリン', 'Jane Birkin Medley = ジェーン・バーキン・メドレー', '津軽 ～ 南部俵積み唄', 'It Might As Well Stay Monday From Now On = 月曜はブルーな日', 'Time Is On My Side = タイム・イズ・オン・マイ・サイド', 'We Can Talk = ウィ・キャン・トーク', 'Left Alone = レフト・ア
ローン', 'ヨイトマケの唄', 'Mambo No. 5 = マンボ・ナンバー5', '(The White Room ～ Sunshine Of Your Love) ～ Knockin On Heavens Door = 天国への扉', 'Welcome To My Rhythm [こんなオイラに誰がした] ～ 嵐を呼ぶ男'], 'combinations': ['Welcome To My Life 1998', 'Shuichi Murakam
i 1998', 'Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life', 'Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life 1998']}}
json data =  {'tags': {'releaseArtist': ['Shuichi Murakami', 'Nobu Caine', 'Electro Keyboard Orchestra', 'Mash', 'Loser', 'Ponta Box', 'Mobo Band', 'JOQR DJ Girls', 'Miro Takebi Trio', 'Nobu-Zans', '7 Seven', 'Ponta Unit'], 'releaseInfo': ['Welcome To My Life', '1998', 'Japan', 'JVC', 'Jazz'], 'tracklist': ['Jaco Pastorius Medley = ジャコ・パトリアス・メドレー', 'I Want You Back = アイ・ウォント・ユー・バック', 'Travelling = トラベリング', 'Ive Got You Under My Skin = アイヴ・ガット・ユー・アンダー・マイ・スキン', '青い山脈', 'Oh! Darli
ng = オー！ ダーリン', 'Jane Birkin Medley = ジェーン・バーキン・メドレー', '津軽 ～ 南部俵積み唄', 'It Might As Well Stay Monday From Now On = 月曜はブルーな日', 'Time Is On My Side = タイム・イズ・オン・マイ・サイド', 'We Can Talk = ウィ・キャン・トーク', 'Left Alone =
 レフト・アローン', 'ヨイトマケの唄', 'Mambo No. 5 = マンボ・ナンバー5', '(The White Room ～ Sunshine Of Your Love) ～ Knockin On Heavens Door = 天国への扉', 'Welcome To My Rhythm [こんなオイラに誰がした] ～ 嵐を呼ぶ男'], 'combinations': ['Welcome To My Life 1998', 'Shui
chi Murakami 1998', 'Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life', 'Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life 1998']}}
```

my Python functionr returns the JSON like this:

```
#format tags
tags = {}
tags["releaseArtist"] = artistsTags 
tags["releaseInfo"] = releaseInfoTags
tags["tracklist"] = tracklistTags
tags["combinations"] = combinationsTags
data = {}
data["tags"] = tags
print('finished python tags look like:')
print(data)
return data
```

My javascript in an html file receives the tags json data structure like this:

```
            console.log("ajax request to /my-ajax-test/ was a success !")
            console.log("response = ", response)                                 //encoded output
            console.log("JSON.stringify(response) = ", JSON.stringify(response)) //encoded output
            //console.log("JSON.loads(response) = ", JSON.loads(response))       //no json.loads function
            console.log("JSON.parse(response) = ", JSON.parse(response))         //encoded output
```

When I print the received json data; all the Japanese characters get encoded like `\u9752\u3044\u5c71\u8108`:

```
response =  {"tags": {"releaseArtist": ["Shuichi Murakami", "Nobu Caine", "Electro Keyboard Orchestra", "Mash", "Loser", "Ponta Box", "Mobo Band", "JOQR DJ Girls", "Miro Takebi Trio", "Nobu-Zans", "7 Seven", "Ponta Unit"], "releaseInfo": ["Welcome To My Life", "1998", "Japan", "JVC", "Jazz"], "tracklist": ["Jaco Pastorius Medley = \u30b8\u30e3\u30b3\u30fb\u30d1\u30c8\u30ea\u30a2\u30b9\u30fb\u30e1\u30c9\u30ec\u30fc", "I Want You Back = \u30a2\u30a4\u30fb\u30a6\u30a9\u30f3\u30c8\u30fb\u30e6\u30fc\u30fb\u30d0\u30c3\u30af", "Travelling = \u30c8\u30e9\u30d9\u30ea\u30f3\u30b0", "Ive Got You Under My Skin = \u30a2\u30a4\u30f4\u30fb\u30ac\u30c3\u30c8\u30fb\u30e6\u30fc\u30fb\u30a2\u30f3\u30c0\u30fc\u30fb\u30de\u30a4\u30fb\u30b9\u30ad\u30f3", "\u9752\u3044\u5c71\u8108", "Oh! Darling = \u30aa\u30fc\uff01 \u30c0\u30fc\u30ea\u30f3", "Jane Birkin Medley = \u30b8\u30a7\u30fc\u30f3\u30fb\u30d0\u30fc\u30ad\u30f3\u30fb\u30e1\u30c9\u30ec\u30fc", "\u6d25\u8efd \uff5e \u5357\u90e8\u4ff5\u7a4d\u307f\u5504", "It Might As Well Stay Monday From Now On = \u6708\u66dc\u306f\u30d6\u30eb\u30fc\u306a\u65e5", "Time Is On My Side = \u30bf\u30a4\u30e0\u30fb\u30a4\u30ba\u30fb\u30aa\u30f3\u30fb\u30de\u30a4\u30fb\u30b5\u30a4\u30c9", "We Can Talk = \u30a6\u30a3\u30fb\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30fb\u30c8\u30fc\u30af", "Left Alone = \u30ec\u30d5\u30c8\u30fb\u30a2\u30ed\u30fc\u30f3", "\u30e8\u30a4\u30c8\u30de\u30b1\u306e\u5504", "Mambo No. 5 = \u30de\u30f3\u30dc\u30fb\u30ca\u30f3\u30d0\u30fc5", "(The White Room \uff5e Sunshine Of Your Love) \uff5e Knockin On Heavens Door = \u5929\u56fd\u3078\u306e\u6249", "Welcome To My Rhythm [\u3053\u3093\u306a\u30aa\u30a4\u30e9\u306b\u8ab0\u304c\u3057\u305f] \uff5e \u5d50\u3092\u547c\u3076\u7537"], "combinations": ["Welcome To My Life 1998", "Shuichi Murakami 1998", "Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life", "Shuichi Murakami Welcome To My Life 1998"]}}
```

So the json data is fine when its in Python, but once it reaches javascript it encodes complex chars, and my attempts to decode it with json.parse / json.loads / json.stringify havent been successfull. Is there a way to ensure that my Javascript always has the same chars as in Python? (For languages with chars like Japan, Middle Eastern, etc...)

Comment: A very old story. You need to use `json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False)`.

Answer (score 1):

fixed with

```
resolve(JSON.parse(response))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
import json

tags = {}
tags["releaseArtist"] = artistsTags 
tags["releaseInfo"] = releaseInfoTags
tags["tracklist"] = tracklistTags
tags["combinations"] = combinationsTags
data = {}
data["tags"] = tags
return json.dumps({'data': data, 'ensure_ascii'=False})
```